# Error during mfp app webupdate for implementing direct update functionality

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mfp, direct-update

I have tried to check direct update provided by ibm mobile first.
after changing the web resources to upload my new application to mfp console 
i tried to run: mfpdev app webupdate
console output:

Deploying to server:'http://10.207.135.166:9080' runtime:'mfp'
Error: Web resources could not be deployed for platform: ios
Error: The mfpdev app webupdate command failed: INVALIDPLATFORMVERSION

Comment: Update the description with the output of 'mfpdev app webupdate -dd'

Comment: Do you see this issue only on iOS or android as well ? what is your mfpdev -v ,cordova -v ,cordova platform list ,cordova-plugin-mfp version